# Octopus Deploy multiple SQL scripts for specific database connections

Tags: .net-core, azure-pipelines, octopus-deploy, octopus

I have automated my DevOps continuous deployment with octopus. I've create a package of my WebApp and migration sql script. This will successfully deploy on the SQL-server. But now I want to run specific .sql scripts, within my octopus package, on specific databases/servers.

For example: script1.sql needs to be run on:

```
Server=DTAP-L-SQL01\TEST;Database=Octopus_Test;Integrated Security=True; and script script2.sql needs to be run on Server=DTAP-L-SQL02\TEST;Database=Octopus_Test;Integrated Security=True;
```

Is it possible to set this up dynamically? I've searched the entire internet but nothing came close to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this through `Scoping Variables`. From the Octopus deploy [documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/variables/scoping-variables):

> The variables that you define for your projects in Octopus can be
>   scoped in the following ways:
>
> - Environments (most common).
> - Deployment targets.
> - Target roles.
> - Deployment steps.
> - Channels.
> - Tenants.

I think what you are looking for here is the `Target` role.